# Line integral of a rational function

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis

Let $P(z)$ be a polynomial such that all the roots of $P(z)$ are inside a circle around the origin with radius $R$.
Calculate $\int_{|z|=R}\frac{1}{P(z)}dz$.
I know you can use partial function decomposition to decompose $\frac{1}{P(z)}$ into a sum of fractions such that on every function you can use Cauchy's integral formula to compute the integral. I can't find anything about the coefficients of the decomposed fractions for the integral formula. Note that I cannot use the general Cauchy's integral formula, I can only use it on an integral over a circle.

Comment: Do you know the residue theorem?

Comment: No, but I'm pretty sure I cannot use it either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $P$ is constant, $\frac{1}{P(z)}$ is an entire function (since $P \equiv 0$ has zeros outside the disk with radius $R$, we have $P \not\equiv 0$), and hence

$$\int_{\lvert z\rvert = R} \frac{1}{P(z)}\,dz = 0.$$

If $\deg P = 1$, $P(z) = az+b$ with $a\neq 0$, then

$$\int_{\lvert z\rvert = R} \frac{1}{P(z)}\,dz = \frac{1}{a}\int_{\lvert z\rvert = R} \frac{1}{z+\frac{b}{a}}\,dz,$$

which you can evaluate with Cauchy's integral formula.

If $\deg P > 1$, use Cauchy's integral theorem to conclude

$$\int_{\lvert z\rvert = R} \frac{1}{P(z)}\,dz = \int_{\lvert z\rvert = n\cdot R} \frac{1}{P(z)}\,dz$$

for all $n > 1$, and use the standard estimate/estimation lemma to find the value.

Comment: What do you mean by standard estimate lemma and why did you integrate over the larger circle $nR$?

Comment: The standard estimate (or estimation lemma) is $$\left\lvert \int_\gamma f(z)\,dz\right\rvert \leqslant L(\gamma)\cdot \sup \{ \lvert f(\zeta)\rvert : \zeta \in \operatorname{Tr}\gamma\},$$ where $L(\gamma)$ is the length of $\gamma$, and $\operatorname{Tr}\gamma$ the trace of the path. What happens when you let $n\to\infty$?